# Android:startActivityForResult( ) is not calling

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I have one application in that when I click on settings button, I need to move to another activity which contains tabs. I build up all the code and it is working well for Acer tab. When I run the same application in Samsung Galaxy(4.1.1) It is showing "Unfortunately,app has stopped" error. Check my code below:

```
settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent prefIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Preferences.class);
                startActivityForResult(prefIntent, 0);
           }
    });
```

//Preferences.java

```
   setContentView(R.layout.preferences);
    private Button pref_close;
    pref_close   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close_prefs);
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("wifi").setIndicator("Wifi Settings",null).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent(this, AppSettings.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("settings").setIndicator(" Clock Settings",null).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    pref_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //finish();
                             setResult(RESULT_OK);
        }
    });
```

The issue is here when I comment the startActivityForResult() then my app is not force closing and preferences.java file is not calling. In my logcat show any errors, but showing as

```
03-28 11:30:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(4668): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.vision.clock/com.vision.clock.activity.Preferences}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.wifi.WifiPickerActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Given caller package com.android.settings is not running in process ProcessRecord
```

I'm not getting solution to find out the issue.. Can anybody find out the solution.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: hi! if you are using activity group than put onActivityResult to Activity group class,like if your activity group name is group1 and you are in class class1 which is a class of activity group "group1" than put your OnACtivityResult code on group1 class

Answer (score 0):

```
settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent prefIntent = new Intent(v.getApplicationContext(), Preferences.class);
                startActivityForResult(prefIntent, 0);
           }
    });
```

Change v.getContext() into v.getApplicationContext()

Comment: I am getting error The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type View. in this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not passing any data back from Preference Activity to the first activity, you do not need to implement startActivityForResult in the first place.

In First Activity:

```
settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent prefIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Preferences.class);
                startActivityForResult(prefIntent);
           }
    });
```

In Preferences activity:

```
pref_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

first Activity

```
 settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent prefIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Preferences.class);
            startActivityForResult(prefIntent, 0);
       }
});

 ////this one add to your first activity after oncreate close

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       // your code  
             }
         }
```

Preferences.java

```
  pref_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) { 

      setResult(RESULT_OK);
      finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: you mean we need to add onActivityResult() method in second class i.e preferences.java right

Comment: Actually all the code was written in onResume() function. after onCreate function I called onActivityResult() function and called onResume function in if loop as you said. but giving error.

Comment: Can you have any other ideas regarding this. @NagarjunaReddy